# how do a dynamic grid in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

in each round I get the data I need to show, but the question is how can I generate rows of 5 columns in a loop using php?

```
while ($query->have_posts()) {
echo $query->the_post();
$id=get_the_id();

$imagen_ruta = get_post_custom_values($img = 'main_image');

$imagen = explode(",", $imagen_ruta[0]); 

echo "<img style='width:200px; height:300px;' src='". 
wp_get_attachment_url($imagen[0])."'>";

$nombre= get_post_custom_values($name = '_job_title');

$precio_1hora = get_post_custom_values($hora = '_precio_1hra');

echo " <br>".$nombre[0]." ".$precio_1hora[0];

$lugar_trabajo= get_post_custom_values($key = '_job_location');

echo " <br>".$lugar_trabajo[0];

echo "</div><br>";
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using wordpress @Chris

Answer (score 0):

use a table
your php would be something like this

```
echo "<table>";

while(condition){
  echo "< tr>";
  echo "< td> *your data here* < /td>"; // 5 such td for 5 columns
  echo " < /tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

the < tr > tags will ensure that you get a new row each time.
hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for exactly 5, the keys of each of the arrays match, and there will always be at least 5 values in them, try this:

```
//fill the arrays
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $post[] = $query->the_post();

    $imagen_ruta = get_post_custom_values($img = 'main_image');

    $imagen = explode(",", $imagen_ruta[0]); 

    $nombre= get_post_custom_values($name = '_job_title');

    $precio_1hora = get_post_custom_values($hora = '_precio_1hra');

    $lugar_trabajo= get_post_custom_values($key = '_job_location');
}

//output the contents
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
    echo $post[$x];

    echo "<img style='width:200px; height:300px;' src='". 
    wp_get_attachment_url($imagen[$x])."'>";

    echo " <br>".$nombre[$x]." ".$precio_1hora[$x];

    echo " <br>".$lugar_trabajo[$x];

    echo "</div><br>";
}
```

There may need to be some tweaks here, so let me know if this doesn't do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do something like this would be using a for loop with two variable, I'll use $i and $j in this example (I am assuming `$query->the_post()` is an array):

```
$posts = $query->the_post();

for($i=0, $j=1, $i < count($posts), $i++, $j++){

if($j == 5){
//Start New Column Here
$j=1;
}
//Create rows in your format here

}
```